# Update to El Capitan and Xcode 7.1 gave me terrible default transitions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I just got this update and all of the sudden all of my segues have this terrible 5 second long transition.  I turned off animation for the segues on my storyboard and it stopped the animation but it is still there for the unwind segues.

I created a test app to work on this and it is just 2 views in a navigation controller. and a single button to move from view a to b.

I tried creating a custom segue but that got rid of my navigation bar completely so all that does not help.  I tried overriding the 'segueForUnwindingToViewController' in my navigationController class and that did absolutely nothing.

I am not sure what to do about this and I really need to get rid of these transitions...or even better I would like to customize them (especially the duration).

Comment: thanks for the tip wont update to xcode 7.1

Comment: @PrasanjitDey, I'd recommend the update, but make sure you don't check Slow Animations! It cause me not a small amount of terror...

Comment: I am more worried about swift and moving to swift 2.1 hope it does not break all my code like the xcode 7 did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you hit **Slow Animations** at some point. Under the debug menu in the simulator, uncheck Slow Animations, or just hit **command-T**.

Comment: You are a life saver!  I was in the code trying to override things for hours.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, it killed me too! It's always the little things... Wanna mark as solved then?

Comment: yea I will.  It says I have to wait 5 minutes :P